# call input focus change for Angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a several input boxes that uses filter search binding. So when i delete a character the display results automatically updates.
But i have many input boxes and i dont want to navigate my mouse to each input and manually deleting text.

So what i did is have a function that clears out the text in all of the input boxes

```
 function clearForm() {
    $('#searchcompanyName').val('');
    $('#searchbusinessLN').val('');
... and so on
```

This clears out the forms but it doesnt update angular search results. How could get angular to update what is in the input

```
.controller('srchJobOrdersCtrl', function (Jobs, socketio) {
var vm = this;

vm.search = {
    date: '', companyName: '', businessLN: '',      
    guideName: '', guideLN: '', phoneNum: '', citizenshipNo: '',    
    totalPeople: '', cashChina: '', cashThailand: '', tourManNo: '', licensePlate: '',

    arrvDate: '',
    deptDate: '',
    arrFltNo: '',
    staying: '',
    deptNo: '',
    time: '',

    cashThailand: '',
    cashThailand: '',


};

Jobs.getJobsOrders()
    .success(function(data) {
        vm.jobOrders = data;
    });

vm.clearSearch = function() {
        vm.search = {
        date: '', companyName: '', businessLN: '',      
        guideName: '', guideLN: '', phoneNum: '', citizenshipNo: '',    
        totalPeople: '', cashChina: '', cashThailand: '', tourManNo: '', licensePlate: '',

        arrvDate: '',
        deptDate: '',
        arrFltNo: '',
        staying: '',
        deptNo: '',
        time: '',

        cashThailand: '',
        cashThailand: '',
    };
};
```

HTML

```
<label id='searchLabelT' class='searchLabel'></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control inputWidth3" placeholder="" id='searchcompanyName' ng-model='search.companyName'>
<input type="text" class="form-control inputWidth3" placeholder="" id='searchbusinessLN' ng-model='search.businessLN'>
<input type="text" class="form-control inputWidth3" placeholder="" id='searchguideName' ng-model='search.guideName'>
<input type="text" class="form-control inputWidth3" placeholder="" id='searchguideLN' ng-model='search.guideLN'>
<input type="text" class="form-control inputWidth3" placeholder="" id='searchphoneNum' ng-model='search.phoneNum'>



<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="each in allJobsOrder.jobOrders | reverse | filter:search">
<td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
<td>{{ each.date }}</td>
<td>{{ each.companyName }}</td>
<td>{{ each.businessLN }}</td>
<td>{{ each.guideName }}</td>
<td>{{ each.guideLN }}</td>
<td>{{ each.phoneNum }}</td>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML code of the input boxes. So that would be even better to explain you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use jQuery to update input boxes. Just set corresponding model values to empty. So your controller function will look something like this:

```
$scope.clearForm = function() {
    $scope.search.companyName = '';
    $scope.search.businessLN = '';
    // ... and so on
};
```

Above example implies that you have bindings set up like `ng-model="search.companyName"`, etc.

Comment: Hi Dfsq.... i try doing this but is not clearing forms. Please see my edit post above

Comment: Ive re-edit my post.... my code is really long so i had to cut it out for readable sake.
Why inst when i do vm.search.companyName = ''; doesnt clear my form

Answer (score 0):

Jquery clears the input but doesn’t updates the angular models .

To get your work done , you can create a button for clearing the inputs with an onclick function in angular :

```
<button ng-click="clearForm()">Clear</button>
```

This will call a function in your controller

```
$scope.clearForm = function() {
    $scope.search.companyName = ''; // binds to ng-model='search.companyName'
    $scope.search.businessLN = ''; // binds to ng-model='search.businessLN'
    // ... and so on
};
```

This method will clear values from your angular model as will as your input values.